# List items overlay on floated image

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have scratched my head about this a couple of times now, and I can't figure it out.

This is the code:

```
<div class='imgpos_5'>
    <a href='http://jonaseklundh.se'>
        <img src='http://jonaseklundh.se/bilder/icons/archive.png' width=50 height=50>
    </a>
</div>
<ol>
    <li>List item that is quite long and will wrap when reacing the image
    <li>List item
    <li>List item
    <li>List item
</ol>
```

With the CSS:

```
.imgpos_5 {
    float: right;
}
```

(JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5q9zo4te/)
But the list items overlay on the image, making the link not work correctly. You can only click the image link where there are no list items that span over it - yet the *content* of the list items are properly wrapped. How do I fix this?

(EDIT: The actual percentage/pixel width of the imgpos_5 div is unknown to the code, it can contain multiple images, all floated right. The code can not hard-code the width of either the imgpos_5 or the OL tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.imgpos_5 {
  float: right;

}
.listItem {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='imgpos_5'>
  <a href='http://jonaseklundh.se'>
    <img src='http://jonaseklundh.se/bilder/icons/archive.png' width=50 height=50>
  </a>
</div>
<ol class="listItem">
  <li>List item that is quite long and will wrap when reacing the image</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Like I said to Praveen Kumar - the code has no way to know whether the imgpos_5 will be 20% or 90%, so this is not a workable solution. I need a solution that can handle any given width of the impos DIV

Comment: Yeah, it helped with the jsfiddle, so you've solved the problem. My problem now is that it doesn't actually solve it in my production environment. But I'll mark your answer as correct and I have to work from there.

Answer (score 1):

Give a `clear: both` on the `<ul>`:

```
ol {clear: both;}
```

Or, give width and float the `<ul>`:

```
.imgpos_5 {float: right; width: 40%;}
ol {float: left; width: 40%;}
```

Comment: ol { clear: both; } will put the list under the image, and the code doesn't know what width the "impos_5" div will be, it can contain one or more images, most with percentage widths....

Comment: @Sandman Yeah, try the second one and let me know then, try with different variations.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear - I can not hard-code any widths to any of these tags. The width of the imgpos_5 is determined by its contents, if it has two 50 pixel images, it will be 100 pixels wide, and thus the OL should occupy the rest of the space to its left. "imgpos_5" does not determine size, only position of the images (floated right)